# Set filetype for files without an extension

Tags: vim

To set a `.txt` file to appear as markdown I can do:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt colorscheme OceanicNext
```

Is there a way to set a filetype for files without an extension at all? For example, if the file is called `notes` (no extension). How could I apply a certain colorscheme to it, such as:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead <no-extension> colorscheme PaperColor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^.]\+` pattern. However, there are some points.

1. `BufNewFile,BufRead` events are for FileType detection and possibly for one-time buffer contents manipulation and such. All settings change are normally done on `FileType` event instead (this way you can support manual filetype setting too).
2. Again, you should use `augroup`, or better put your script under `~/.vim/ftdetect/`  subdirectory to use standard one.
3. File pattern could possibly be more selective.

So, for example,

> ~/.vim/ftdetect/mynotes.vim

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead [a-z]\+ setf mynotes
```

> ~/.vim/ftplugin/mynotes.vim

```
" standard preamble
if exists('b:did_ftplugin')
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1

" tweak some buffer-local options
let b:undo_ftplugin = 'setl foo< bar< baz<'
setlocal foo bar baz
```